# no output operations registered, so nothing to execute

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i want to filter an incoming json coming from kafka server and based on some version type i need to separate and parse them and do certain computations on them individually. But here when iam using if statements iam getting the error "no output operations registered" as iam using the print statement inside the if statements. what must be the alternative to run the code? thanks in advance.

`enter code here`

```
if(packetType.equals("P300")) {
      val three300s=dstream.map(parser300)
       three300s.print()
      }
else if(packetType.equals("P30")) {
      val thirty30s=dstream.map(parser30)
      thirty30s.print()
 }
else if(packetType.equals("P6")) {
      val six6s=dstream.map(parser6)
      six6s.print()  
   }
 ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()


    }
  }
```

iam getting the " Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable". i observed some problem with serialization but could not find out exactly.

```
enter code here
pType.map(rdd => {
   val pkt= rdd.toString()
  if(pkt.equals("P300")) {

  val t300=dstream.map(par300)
   t300.print()
 }else if(pkt.equals("P30")) {
    val t30=dstream.map(par30)
    t30.print()        
 }else if(pkt.equals("P6")) {
    val t6=dstream.map(par6)
    t6.print()        
 }
})
```

Comment: you should do some actions like count in dstream to get the  output.

Comment: @Knight71 FYI, count on dstream is not an action.

Comment: @avr thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @avr can you check the new one.thanks

Comment: @vivek it would be better if you start new thread instead of updating this question. By that your new question will be visible to everyone and there are high chances that your problem get resolved quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `packetType` is not matching with any case you provided. Can you add `else` statement also as provided below.

```
else{
  dstream.print(1)
}
```

It will certainly eliminate the error you are getting. Or else you need to make sure `packetType` is matching with any one of case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the above suggestion, i will check with this and reach you again.

Comment: @vivek, have you tried it? Let me know if it worked or you are facing any issues!

Comment: yaah i tried it, it is working with else statement but i found that packetType in above statement is in dstream code though iam passing it in string.......so, it is not validating with "P300"..........i will discuss with the team and try to put full code or some alternative code.....thanks fr ur concern